# Best slot in the fuse box to plug a hard wire kit for dash cam

Tags: toyota, fuse, prius, fuse-panel, dashcam

I brought a Pruveeo Hard Wire Kit for Dash Cam and trying to plug it in to my car (Prius C) fuse box. I have a couple of questions regarding this.

1. Should I remove one fuse (Say fuse for the viper) and plug the hard wire kit's socket with the fuse there (hard wire kit comes with a fuse but there is no additional slot in the kit to add the fuse taken out from the fuse slot)
2. Plug the hard wire kit's socket to an empty slot (slot that gives power when engine is on)

I checked some videos and all of them do this by removing an existing one and plug this to that slot.

Can someone help me on this. I could add a image of the fuse box if needed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!